# jquery "Filtering" a ul/li "tree" of data to show all children when a filter is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Given a tree of information, I have a need to "filter" the data in such a way that if someone queries for "Beta", they see Category 1 > Beta > ShowThisasWell

A crucial point is that these `<ul><li><div>` are created by some other component from json data. For the time being, I'm only concerned about the case where the nodes are created in dom. I'll figure out how to invoke the code to filter the actual data.

```
       <div>
         <ul>
           <li>
              <div>Category 1</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                     <div>Beta</div>
                     <ul>
                       <li>
                          <div>ShowThisasWell</div>
                       </li>
                      </ul>
                 </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please add the libs you are using. Which component is creating the lists?

Comment: Is there any specific pattern for the tree? Are you allowed to change it so that you can insert ids or classes to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter(query) {
    $('li').hide();
    $('li li > div').each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == query) {
            $(this).parents('li').show();
            $(this).next().find('li').show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is specific to the code you provided, and will probably need to be tweaked (I'd add an id / class on your parent div to identify it within the document).
JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/va7yh/